# I'm making an app in React Native that displays items from a JSON file. It works for one list I created, but not another

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on an app that's supposed to display a few items from a JSON file. I was able to get it to work with a list of names from a separate JSON file, but the different JSON file I'm using doesn't work. Here's my code from the JSON reader file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { Icon } from "native-base";

class LikesTab extends Component {
  //SETTING THE STATE MAKING AN EMPTY ARRAY WHICH WE FIL
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  //Getting the data
  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "http://api.jsonbin.io/b/5b3a49c8a5a2f34ea6b0fbc8"
    );

    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    this.setState({ data: json.entry });
  };

  //var customData = require('./customData.json');

  //Setting what is shown
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.resource.medicationCodeableConcept.text}</Text>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default LikesTab;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

The link to the JSON file is this:
http://api.jsonbin.io/b/5b3a49c8a5a2f34ea6b0fbc8

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

fetch() should be used inside **componentDidMount()**. Asynchronous calls won't execute properly inside componentWillMount() which is used in your code.

This is also mentioned in the React docs.

Here's a site explaining why this is so:

[Where to Fetch Data](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/)

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't have good support for async component lifecycle methods. You'll need to use something like [redux-thunk or redux-saga to use async/await with React](http://thecodebarbarian.com/async-await-with-react-and-redux-thunk.html).